# How to export MySQL database table values into JSon file in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I am creating a project using C# and MYSQL. I have the records in the database. I want to export the records in the table (tbl_sales) into a JSon file using SELECT query.

```
table name : tbl_sales 

+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|sale_item | sale_qty |       added_on      |    last_updated_on  |
+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Fruits   |    56    | 2018-05-12 14:28:27 | 2018-05-14 10:27:29 |
| Sugar    |     3    | 2017-11-14 04:24:15 | 2018-05-13 05:22:14 |
| Biscuit  |    20    | 2018-05-01 18:47:19 | 2018-05-07 06:24:08 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I tried the following coding :
using Newtonsoft.JSON;

```
public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(DataTable table) {  
   string JSONString=string.Empty;  
   JSONString = JSONConvert.SerializeObject(table);  
   return JSONString;  
}
```

But I got error `The name 'JSONConvert' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: "Please give me the solution." Sorry, but no. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: The OP has edited the question and included what they have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have added `using Newtonsoft.JSON`, but it should be `using Newtonsoft.Json` (note the capitalization).

Similarly, it's `JsonConvert`, not `JSONConvert`.

Also, the reference may not have been added yet.
If that is the case, then you should also have this error message:

> The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

To add it as a reference, Newtonsoft must be added to your project. To do this, you go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager and select the "Browse" tab. There, you enter "Newtonsoft".  From there, you can see the Newtonsoft libary and install it.
Installing it should automatically add it as a reference.

After the reference is added to the project, the errors should disappear.

Comment: @SakthybaalanSanthanakumaran Are you also getting the error message "are you missing a using direcitve or assembly reference?" And if you look at the "References" in the Solution Explorer, do you see "Newtonsoft.Json" in there?

Comment: Yes, it is in there

Comment: @SakthybaalanSanthanakumaran I think I found the problem... the capitalization was wrong. It should be `JsonConvert`, not `JSONConvert`. I've edited the answer. Please check if this solves your problem!

Comment: I changed as yours, but I got error `The type or namespace name 'SerializeObject' does not exist in the namespace 'Json' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`